# Using CSS to style Ruby objects in erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css

I have Googled around but can't find the answer to this question.  How do I use CSS to edit RUby objects in erb.  For example:

```
<%= f.label :email, "Enter your email address for updates" %><br />
<%= f.text_field :email %>
```

Here, I want to use CSS to style the text and the form box.  How can I do that?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use the `:class` option to specify a CSS class:

```
<%= f.text_field :email, :class => "login" %>
```

and then put that in your css:

```
input.login {
  color: red;
}
```

Also, you can specify inline CSS if you want:

```
<%= f.text_field :email, :style => "color: red;" %>
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding on to what Dylan said...

You can use :id option to specify a CSS id:

```
<%= image_tag "illustrations/clipboard.png", :id => "clipboard" %>
```

and then put in your css:

```
#clipboard {
     border: 1px solid #000;
}
```