# How do I add rails form code to bootstrap css

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to style a simple Ruby on rails form with the Twitter Bootstrap css but I'm struggling to workout which bits of rails code goes into which part of the Bootstrap css for a form.

For example where would the following line fit into the Bootstrap css for a form? :

```
<%= f.text_field :company %>
```

Comment: Do you mean how do you add a class/ID to your form input(s)?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the examples in the Twitter Bootstrap documentation, I am assuming you are attempting to apply the form-control class to your input. If this is the case, you would do it like this.

```
<%= f.text_field :company, :class => "form-control" %>
```

See similar question: [Using CSS to style Ruby objects in erb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5108114/using-css-to-style-ruby-objects-in-erb)

Answer (score 0):

`<%= f.text_field :company %>`

Actually, this code means "Create a markup input of type text, with the good name (ex: user[company]) so Rails can handle the parameter easily". No more no less.

Example Output:

```
<input type="text" name="user[company]">
```

Bootstrap will envelope then this object with a style provided by CSS. So

1- Ensure your css is loaded into your "application.css"

Usually, you'll need to add style for the form

```
  <%= form_for @resource, html: { class: "form form-inlined" }  do |f| %>
```

And also around your input text field:

```
  <div class="form-group">
     <%= f.label :company %>
     <%= f.text_field  :company, class: "form-input" %>
  </div>
```

This is just an example, but you can see where to put the bootstrap class on each elements.